# VSS Information: Where do I find it?

Tags: backup, vss

I'm currently taking care of backups for about 100 clients, and I'm really getting hammered with VSS issues.  I've tried many different things, re-regsitering the VSS Dlls, reboots, patches, etc.

What I want to know:  **Where can I find some detailed, technical information about VSS.**

Comment: What, exactly, are you looking for?  Specifically troubleshooting?  Or how VSS is integrated into the OS and the API calls?  How it deals with log truncation?  What you are asking is somewhat broad.

Comment: What issues are you having, specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [How Volume Shadow Copy Service Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785914(WS.10).aspx)

and for probably more than you ever wanted to know:

[Volume Shadow Copy Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968832(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: there's even more stuff over at MSDN if you search for "VSS backup" against the site.

Comment: I get the same info I already posted when I search that however there are more hits about writers (but that's not being asked- and it's almost a whole 'nother topic)